# Change the bg-color when the value change jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Recently I worked on a simple web page on my own, and I faced a problem.
I want to change the `background-color` on a specific cell when the value change.

- if the value is 0 = white
- if there is other value = blue.

I think I am not too far from reality but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $("#table td[id^='changeBgColor']").on('change', function(e) {
        var data = $(this).val();
            if(data === '0'){
                $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
            }else{
                $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
            }
      });
    
})
```

That's the part of the table where the cell is.

```html
<tfoot>
    <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center"><strong>TOTAL</strong></td>
    <td id='changeBgColor' colspan="1" style="text-align: center"><strong>..</strong></td>
    <td id='changeBgColor' colspan="1" style="text-align: center"><strong>..</strong></td>
    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center"><strong></strong></td>
</tfoot>
```

Comment: Is the id of your table `table`? I am asking since you are not showing the full table, here...

Comment: Also, you cannot have multiple element with the same id in HTML, where here you do have two of id `changeBgColor`

Comment: *The change event occurs when the value of an element has been changed (only works on <input>, <textarea> and <select> elements).* https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_change.asp#:~:text=The%20change%20event%20occurs%20when,when%20a%20change%20event%20occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("td:contains('0')").css('background-color', 'white'); // if the value is 0 white, else blue
```